# Acrobat Reader always crashes

Tags: adobe-acrobat, dialog

When I click on `pdf` on my Desktop, Acrobat Reader pops up a dialogue as here

[image: here:]

and then exits.
What's wrong ? I have windows 8.1

Comment: Uninstall Reader , update Windows including optional updates , update all drivers especially video , restart and install Adobe and test

Comment: Uninstalling Reader and reinstalling may be enough. Avoid adding any unsafe plugins.

Comment: Or use an alternate reader, such as *fast*, free, Sumatra PDF. https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader